# How can I add a custom static label to a Prometheus query\metric?

Tags: devops, prometheus, monitoring, metrics, nomad

Ok, so I have this query right here `container_cpu_reserved` which gives me the following metric:

```
container_cpu_reserved{datacenter="dev-01", instance="worker-02", job="nomad", node_class="core", node_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", node_scheduling_eligibility="eligible", node_status="ready"}
```

I want to add 2 labels more to this query which would be `cloud="aws"` and `account_id="0123456789"`

How can I do this? (sorry I'm pretty new to Prometheus)

Comment: Can you explain in more details, what you are trying to do? Do you want to add some arbitrary labels only to the results of query? Or do you want to add them to all metrics `container_cpu_reserved`? Or do you want something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You could add labels directly in Query, Add two [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) functions arround your PromQL:

```
label_replace(       
    label_replace( 

        container_cpu_reserved,

    "cloud", "aws", "instance", ".*")           
,"account_id", "0123456789", "instance", ".*")
```

But it seems to me that you asked the wrong question (that's why you got this answer).

If you wish to add this labels to all PODs of your Deployment, the right way is to add labels to Deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    cloud: aws
    account_id: 0123456789
...
```